# How will pre-rendering SPA in server side affect client side scripts like ads/analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, phantomjs, single-page-application, prerender

I have to prerender a SPA application written in Angular2 with a WebAPI backend
on the server using a `prerender.io/PhantomJS` middleware for both SEO and performance benefits.
This middleware will load the response in a headless browser and return the output to the client browser.
When this is being done it might cause the ads script and other tracking scripts to be executed.

Am not sure of the impact of this. To be sure I could include these scripts in the pipeline after the page has been prerendered. 
But then again this requires more work and could potentially void any performance benefits of pre-rendering, or I could add a ignore rule in analytics but I could not add such rules in other tracking scripts / ad scripts.

Would this reduce the effectiveness of the ads and other client side scripts being served ? Since it'll be returning an already rendered HTML page back to the browser won't it not stop the scripts from being executed again on the browser and potentially show ads that are not targeted and tracking scripts to be not working ?

I have read the documentation of `prerender.io` but it does not deal with this topic, I could however make use of its backlists and whitelist, but since most of these scripts are included in the `HTML` page am not sure if I could benefit from those features.

Am sure there is a standard solution and would like to understand how to pre-render properly on the server to overcome these quirks.

Comment: The Prerender server, whether run on its own or through our hosted service, will abort any requests to URLs that match any of these strings: https://github.com/prerender/prerender/blob/master/lib/resources/blocked-resources.json. We do that to prevent Prerender from showing up in your analytics.

Comment: @Prerender.io thanks for the reply, thats good to know, so this is how it works, loads webpage executes all scripts including local angular/framework specific scripts apart from those in the blacklist, but once this lands in the user's browser then those analytics/other scripts are executed ? by now your framework specific tags in the DOM are converted to HTML elements and only those other scripts gets executed ?

Comment: Prerendered pages should only be served to crawlers (not users) and the Prerender server will remove any <script> tags from the page after it's been rendered. So the crawlers shouldn't have any javascript to execute.